# Create SecureString from unmanaged unicode string

Tags: c#, unicode, pinvoke, marshalling, securestring

I am wanting to try to tie the CryptUnprotectData windows API function and the .net SecureString together the best way possible.  CryptUnprotectData returns a DATA_BLOB structure consisting of an array of bytes and a byte length.  In my program this will be a Unicode UTF-16 string.  SecureString has a constructor which takes a char* and length params, so I would like to be able to do something like:

```
SecureString ss = SecureString((char*)textBlob.pbData, textBlob.cbData / 2);
```

This works, except UTF-16 is variable length, so I don't really know what to use as the length argument.  The above example assumes 2 byte characters (BMP), but for other planes it could be up to 4 bytes.  I need to know the number of UTF-16 characters in the byte array.  What is the best way to do this without copying the values around in memory (thereby compromising security).  I plan on zeroing out and freeing the byte array as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Windows API deals with UTF-16 code points as far as I'm aware - in other words, you treat surrogate pairs as two code points instead of a single character. Given that the constructor for SecureString is dealing with a pointer to .NET `System.Char` values (which are UTF-16) I think the code snippet you've got is fine - the number of elements in pbData *is* half its size in bytes.

For instance if `pbData` contained (just) a surrogate pair, `cbData` would be 4 and you'd still want to pass in 2 as the second argument - because that's the number of `System.Char` values you're constructing the `SecureString` from. The fact that it's one non-BMP unicode character is irrelevant to the number of UTF-16 `System.Char` values it's represented in.

(And yes, the support for non-BMP data is a bit of a mess, and I suspect very few people get it right everywhere. I'm sure I don't. Fortunately in many places you don't need to worry...)

Comment: Thanks alot Jon, that makes perfect sense!  This stuff all still new to me.